# Is "RGB Int Int Int | Transparent" a sum or product type?

Tags: haskell

#### Sum type

The `Maybe Int` type is a sum type.

```
data Maybe Int = Nothing | Just Int
```

From my understanding, this is due to the fact that the `Nothing` value constructor takes no arguments and the second value constructor called `Just` takes only one argument. Therefore, because no value constructor takes more than one argument, this type is a product type.

#### Product type

The type below is a product type since its data constructor takes two arguments and therefore is a product type.

```
data Colour = Person String Int
```

However, I am not sure how we would classify the following type in the context of the *sum and product types*. How should we refer to this?

```
data Shade = RGB Int Int Int | Transparent
```

Comment: I would just go with "algebraic data type" aka "ADT"

Comment: A *hetrogenous* type?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All `data` types are "sums of products".
We sum over the number of constructors, and for each constructor we multiply over the number of arguments.

Sometimes the sum is trivial. When there is a single constructor, or none at all, we sum over a singleton or empty set. Summing over a single constructor makes the resulting type isomorphic to a product. Summing over no constructors makes the type to be empty (e.g. `Data.Void.Void`).

Sometimes, some of the products are trivial as well. When there is a single argument, or none at all, we multiply over a singleton or empty set. Multiplying over a single argument `T` simply produces `T` (after lifting). Multiplying over no arguments produces a type with only one value (e.g. `()`).

Hence, sometimes our `data` is a non-trivial sum of trivial products, and we call it a "sum"; sometimes it is a trivial sum of non-trivial products, and we call it a "product". But, in the general case, it is always a "sum of products".

Note that algebraic types (up to isomorphism) form a commutative semiring, satisfying roughly the same laws of high school algebra for sums and products. In high school algebra, we can turn any expression involving nested sums and products into a polynomial, i.e. into a "sum of products". This also happens with types (up to isomorphism), hence the choice of making `data` types to be "sums of products" is rather expressive.

Comment: Re. the last paragraph OP might check out Chris Taylor's series here: http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/10/the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types/

Answer (score 2):

The `Maybe Int` type is a sum type because it has an alternation

```
data SumType = This | That
```

the fact that it has arguments on its constructors doesn't affect its "sum-ness." Sum types can also contain product constructors, such as:

```
type Username = String
type Email    = String
-- User is a sum of three products
data User = NotLoggedIn                    -- nullary constructor
          | Guest Username                 -- unary constructor
          | RegisteredUser Username Email  -- binary constructor
```

Comment: This is like saying `1 + 2 + 2*4` is a product. It isn't. What it (and `User`) is, is sum of products.